# K & R C programming exercise 1-19

Tags: c, string, char, reverse, kernighan-and-ritchie

The assignment:
 Write a function reverse(s) that reveres the character string s.Use it to write a program that reveres its inputs a line at a time

Here is my attempt at solving it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int  getlinex(char line[], int maxline);

int main(){
    int len, j;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char *temp;
    while ((len = getlinex(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        for(j=0; j<=len; j++){
            temp = &line[len-j];
            line[j] = *temp ;
        }
        printf("%s", line);
    }
}

int getlinex(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;
    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++) {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Second version

```
int getlinex(char line[], int maxline);

int main(){
    int len,j;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    while ((len = getlinex(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        for(j=0;j<=len;j++){
            reverse(&line,j,len);
        }
        printf("%s",line);
    }
}

void reverse( char *s[], int i, int len){
    s[i] = s[len-i];
}

int getlinex(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;
    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++) {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

When I input a string of character the output is blank.

I have tried returning a char[] array but it doesn't work only in main i get to do the processing on the string.

Where is the problem ?

Comment: I see no function `reverse()`, nor indeed `reverses()`.

Comment: `line[len - j]` is the null character at the end when `j == 0`, so your reversed string is empty. You probably want `j < len` instead of `j <= len`, too. And you should swap characters; at the moment you just do a one-way copy from the end to he front.

Answer (score 0):

As it is written in the assignment you have to write a corresponding function. It can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char * reverse( char *s )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[n-i-1];
        s[n-i-1] = s[i];
        s[i] = c;
    }

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "Hello, World!";

    puts( s );
    puts( reverse( s ) );
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello, World!
!dlroW ,olleH
```

As for the loop in your program

```
         for(j=0;j<=len;j++){
            temp = &line[len-j];
            line[j] = *temp ;
            }
```

then it does not make sense. For example when j is equal to 0 then the body of the loop just overwrites `line[0]` with the character stored at `&line[len]` that is equal to the terminating zero of the string. You need to swap characters in the head with characters in the tail of the string.

Take into account that the function `getlinex` includes in the string the new line character.

```
  if (c == '\n') {
    s[i] = c;
    i++;
  }
```

Maybe you should remove it from the string before reversing it.

For example

```
if ( line[len-1] == '\n' ) line[len-1] = '\0';
```

Or just remove the shown above `if` statement from the function `getlinex`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this loop:

```
for(j=0;j<=len;j++){
    temp = &line[len-j];
    line[j] = *temp;
}
```

The very first time through, `j` is `0`, so `temp` is set to `&line[len]`.  Since this points to the terminating `\0` byte of `line`, `*temp` is `\0`.  This is then assigned to `line[j]`, which is `line[0]`.  It doesn't matter what comes after that, since the very first byte of `line` terminates the string.

That explains why you're seeing an empty string as the result.  But even if that particular problem is fixed, the string is being reversed in-place, so once it reaches the middle of the string, the remaining characters will have been overwritten and no longer available.  The fix is to swap pairs of characters, rather than just copying one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I wrote while going through KnR exercises.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* exercise 1.19 */

#define MAXLEN 1000

int getline(char s[], int len);
void reverse(char s[]);

int
main(){
    int len;
    char line[MAXLEN];

    while ((len=getline(line,MAXLEN))){
        reverse(line);
        printf("%d - %s",len, line);
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
 * Reads a line from stdin
 */
int getline(char s[], int len){
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < len -1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    s[i] = c;

    if (c == '\n'){
        s[i] = '\n';
        ++i;
    }

    s[i]='\0';
    return i;
} 


/*
 *  Reverses the order of chracters in string s
 */
void reverse(char s[]){
    int i, k;
    char tmp[MAXLEN];

    i = 0;
    /* copy the character string */
    while ((tmp[i] = s[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;

    --i; /* last character is nil */

    for (k = 0; k <= i ; ++k)
        s[k] = tmp[i-k];

    s[k] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is my implementation. It follows the functional style.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char org[], int maxline);
void reverse(char rev[], char org[], int len);

int main(void) {
    char org[MAXLINE];
    char rev[MAXLINE];
    int len;
    while ((len = getline(org, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        if (len > 0) {
            reverse(rev, org, len);
            printf("%s", rev);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int getline(char org[], int maxline) {
    int i = 0, c;
    for (i = 0; i < maxline - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++) {
        org[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        org[i] = '\n';
        i++;
    }
    org[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void reverse(char rev[], char org[], int len) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        rev[len - i] = org[i];
    }
    rev[0] = '\b';
    rev[1] = '\b';
    rev[len + 1] = '\n';
    rev[len + 2] = '\0';
}
```